# Current Location in react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, geolocation, react-native-maps

I was trying get the current location using `react-native-maps`. This is my following code :

```
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    latitude: 10,
    longitude: 10,
    latitudeDelta: 0.001,
    longitudeDelta: 0.001,
});

useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
}, []);

var options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0,
  };
      
function success(pos) {

 var crd = pos.coords;

 setPosition({
   latitude: crd.latitude,
   longitude: crd.longitude,
   latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
   longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
 });
}

function error(err) {
   console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
}

return (

<MapView
    style={styles.map}
    initialRegion={position}
    showsUserLocation={true}
>
</MapView>
```

Now if I remove the property `initialRegion`, the map is working perfectly fine. But with the above code, I am getting a white screen without any error.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with your code is that `getCurrentPosition` is failing and since your initial coordinates inside `position` are very zoomed in, it looks like it isn't showing anything.

*Also make sure the google maps API is enabled and [react-native-maps is configured correctly](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md).*

Here is how I got it working:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation';

const App = () => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    latitude: 10,
    longitude: 10,
    latitudeDelta: 0.001,
    longitudeDelta: 0.001,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((pos) => {
      const crd = pos.coords;
      setPosition({
        latitude: crd.latitude,
        longitude: crd.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      initialRegion={position}
      showsUserLocation={true}
    />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Actually if I change `initialRegion` to `region` it's working fine, the when I build the app and install the app in my phone, it's same as the above screenshot.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. You say it works if you change `initialRegion` to `region`, but it still looks like the picture when you run it on your phone, so changing it doesn't work?

Comment: Or are you saying changing `initialRegion` to `region` entirely solves your problem?

Comment: It didn't work for me. I had to do some further changes:
1. Added a useRef() object and made it a dependency. 
2. changed initialRegion to region: